# Adding the_category into the_excerpt

Tags: wordpress, blogs, categories

I'd like to begin the_excerpt with the_category on my blog's homepage. I've read through the codex but haven't found a solution. So, If my Post category is "movies" and "the_excerpt" outputs: "Paul Rudd, Emile Hirsch find sublime, subtle comedy in the ... Read More", I'd like it to instead output "MOVIES | Paul Rudd, Emile Hirsch find sublime, subtle comedy in the ... Read More"

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What does your code look like so far?  the_category().' '.the_excerpt() should get your pretty close.

Comment: Thanks andrew - the issue is that the_excerpt is styled as a paragraph with text-alinged center. If it were aligned left, then I could likely use a float on the category and your suggestion would work well. But I need the_category to output as text INSIDE of the_excerpt so that the paragraph text will be properly centered.

Comment: Oh, ok :)  Answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the_excerpt() is actually just a call to the filter with the same name, which passes get_the_excerpt()

```
function the_excerpt() {
    echo apply_filters('the_excerpt', get_the_excerpt());
}
```

In your functions.php file or a plugin, add something like:

```
add_filter('the_excerpt','my_add_category',10,1);
function my_add_category($excerpt) {
    $excerpt = the_category().' | '.$excerpt;
    return $excerpt;
}
```

That's untested, but let me know if it doesn't work and I'll load up a local environment and get you something else.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but when I enter the add_filter code above into my functions.php file and then add my_add_category() to my template, it's only outputting the category. Also, what is the '10' and '1' for in the filter code?

Comment: Oh, go ahead and use the excerpt(), this function tells WordPress to add the category and the "|" before the excerpt itself when the_excerpt() is called. The 10 is the priority that the function is called when WordPress is running through the various filters on the the_excerpt() function. For example, something with priority 11 would run after this. The fourth parameter, the 1, is telling WordPress that our filter function expects one and only one parameter itself.

Comment: Great - thanks for that info. So this does work in that the category is displayed before the excerpt. My next step is to figure out a way to get the category (which is displayed as an li element inside a ul) actually inside the excerpt paragraph so that I can align all of the text centered. Thanks for the help - I'll see if I can get this centering problem to work.